# (VBA) Building a ADODB.Connection to Access from Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-connection, pivot, oledbconnection

I'm been searching for a while and I can't find any help on this issue.

I have a shared Access 2007 database as a source.  I have excel pivots that are linked to a table in that database.  I will utimately have multiple excel files linked to the database (and multiple users), and for that reason I'd like to avoid residual open connection to the DB for Access performance reasons, even if the connections are read only.

I've built the connection in excel, but I am attempting to so is write VBA code to open the connection to the access table refresh the pivot cache, then drop the connection.  I know that I'm not putting the pieces together correctly.  Can someone help me out?  Thank you in advance.

```
Sub ConnectToAccessAttempt()

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DB_Name.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).CommandText = "table_Name"

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll        

End Sub
```

Comment: No error message, and no data connection if established.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I just can't get anywhere with this issue.